# Use of undeclared type "ViewController"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboard

I'm using a library for Tap Bar Controller so I have to change the name of the class controller to `RAMAnimatedTabBarController` to use the features. But in app delegate when I want to present the main bar it displays this error

> Use of undeclared type "RAMAnimatedTabBarController"

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {



    if UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.logged == "logged" {


        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Order") as! RAMAnimatedTabBarController // error here 
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }else{
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as! loginViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Comment: Does `RAMAnimatedTabBarController` extend `UIViewController`?

Comment: UITabBarController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it first. At the beginning of the file, use:
import RAMAnimatedTabBarController